# How to allow some SFTP users SSH access as well?

Tags: sftp

I'm deploying a SFTP server for a team, but some of those users also need SSH access as well to administer the server.

PAM is sssd with our AD. So i can't create separate local users for them to use for SSH, or create separate AD accounts just for SSH access.

Currently, I have this:

```
Match group server_ftp-only
ChrootDirectory /shared
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

If i remove ForceCommand internal-sftp that will allow users to both SFTP and SSH, but I don't want all users to SFTP, only a couple of users.

I tried adding this:

```
Match group server_admins
AllowUsers *
```

But it doesn't work. It appears that the original Match group overrides this second Match group.

One possible solution would be to remove the SSH users from the server_ftp-only security group and into server_admins group, then create a Match group server_admins without ForceCommand internal-sftp, but the server_ftp-only group is populated by team groups (Team-A > server_ftp-only). I really can't create additional groups and separate these users from their team groups.

Comment: *I really can't create additional groups and separate these users from their team groups* — which means, you don't control your environment? Then you have to explain to those who controls it that they must change the users membership. Or list each user individually within each `Match` statement, instead matching by group (which is cumbersome to maintain and, honestly, wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is partly that there is, as far as I know, no way to use a  conditional `Match` block to unset the  `ForceCommand` when that is set as a global default or set by another Match conditional.

So you ***can't do***:

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    # global config ...

    # Enable the internal SFTP server and restrict all users to only SFTP
 
    Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory /shared
    
    # ... 
    
    # Override and remove the ForceCommand sftp-only restriction 
    # for users in the server_admins group 
    
    Match group server_admins
        ChrootDirectory none   <=== this does exist
        ForceCommand    none   <=== this does NOT exist
```

You solve that by implementing a different strategy: don't set the `ForceCommand` as default, keep the defaults somehwat relaxed and then create a slightly more complicated [`Match`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) block  with a [***negated pattern***](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#PATTERNS) to make it apply to  everybody (`*`), ***except*** the members of *`server_admins`* and there you override the defaults and add restrictions :

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# ... 
# your current global config
#
# Enable the internal sftp server but do not set the ForceCommand 

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

# ... 

# Everybody except members of the server_admins group are restricted to SFTP

Match group !server_admins,* 
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory /shared
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

And similar to match the members of *`server_ftp-only`* that are not also a member  of *`server_admins`*

```
Match group !server_admins,server_ftp-only 
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ...
```

Comment: Fantastic! That works just as expected!

Comment: That's great see. In addition please when you want to say "thank you," [vote up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question. - See [this FAQ page](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) with regards to the etiquette on ServerFault and related sites. - (Since this is an Answer to a Question you yourself asked then you additionally have the option to "accept" it as the correct answer.)